# Excel C# cannot update: database read only

Tags: c#, excel, windows

I have 2 PCs:

- Main M = Win 7, 32 bit, Office 2007
- Virtual V = Win 7, 32 bit, Visual Studio 2013

I created 3 Excel files with data on M and sent via network the V machine where I was constructing a program, the thing is the program works fine and updates the Excel sheet on the V machine, bu does not work on my M machine!

I have tried:

- setting permission
- setting "OleDb-Readonly=false;"
- tried it on another machine win7 32bit and 64bit
- tried it on a win10 64bit machine
- creating a new excel file on that machine and copying data to the new
  sheet
- started program as administrator on each step above and without
- Chaning the IMEX between 0 and 1

All of them are not working EXCEPT the V machine... WHY?

Note that the V machine does not have office installed, I am trying to get hold of a machine without the office installed (or one I can uninstall it from) to test it, but not sure if that would actually cause the problem.

Also note I am using an Access 2007 connection in the program as well and it is working fine.

here is the C# update code:

```
 public static bool PreProcess(string dbpath)
{
    //string file = System.IO.Path.Combine("./", dbpath);
    string connStr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;\";", dbpath);

    using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
    {
        conn.Open();
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
        var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        bool notExists;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            notExists = true;
            if (reader[0].ToString().Equals(""))continue;

            for (int cn = 0; cn < list.Count; cn++)
            {
                if (reader[0].ToString().Equals(list[cn]) || reader[0].ToString().Equals(""))
                {
                    new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET [name] = '' WHERE [name]= '" + reader[0].ToString() + "' AND [par1]="+reader[1].ToString()+"", conn).ExecuteNonQuery();
                    notExists = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (notExists)
            {
                list.Add(reader[0].ToString());
                for (int i = 1; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        double d = Double.Parse(reader[i].ToString());
                    }catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        //new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET par"+i+" = '0' WHERE id = '"+reader[0].ToString()+"'");
                        new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET [par"+i+"] = 0 WHERE [name]= '" + reader[0].ToString() + "'", conn).ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    //MessageBox.Show("Data: "+reader[i].ToString() + " - i="+i);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The error:

```
Cannot update. Database or object is read only.
```

Details:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Cannot update. Database or object is read-only.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at KMean.ExcelCon.PreProcess(String dbpath)
   at KMean.Form1.PrePBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
KMean
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Abubakar/Desktop/KMean/KMean/bin/Release/KMean.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

***EDIT***

I have managed to get the V machine to give me the same issue. I changed nothing except the connection string which failed then returned it to it's original status. Now it is gone.... same error: "cannot update..."

Comment: Is there an error message from your application?  If so, please give the entire message and which line number it occurs.

Comment: @cChacon yeah sorry, added it to the post

Comment: Check Access data file Properties on machine 'M'.  Is it "Read only"??

Comment: @cChacon , no it is not, in the end the files were created on machine M and transfered to V then back to M, i did create other new excel sheet on M and tested.. same result.

Comment: What is the exact path passed to the method. Are you sure that this path allows the file to be opened in read/write mode by the current user? Permissions, permissions.....

Comment: @Steve ,yes, i do many manipulations with that file's data, it does get read and processed and displayed, but update is restricted. all users inc this has full control over it permission on it inc. the folder it is in. also program path is folder on desktop and excel is in another folder also on desktop

Answer (score 1):

I had a look, and the open connection is working fine here.

I needed to install the 2016 version of the ACE engine. I see the M machine is running Office 2007. It's unlikely a difference in engine would create a read only problem on connection open; but you never know. It's worth exploring differences in machine configuration when these type of errors happen.

Here is the code I used. This works fine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ExcelReadOnly
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PreProcess("Sample File.xlsx");
            Console.In.ReadLine();
        }

        public static bool PreProcess(string dbpath)
        {
            string connStr = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={dbpath};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;\";";

            using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
            {
                conn.Open();

                var cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", conn);
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader?.Read() == true)
                    Console.Out.WriteLine($"Name: {reader[0]}, Par1: {reader[1]}");
                reader?.Close();

                new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] ([Name], [Par1]) VALUES ('Name 0', '0')", conn)
                    .ExecuteNonQuery();
                new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] ([Name], [Par1]) VALUES ('Name 1', '1')", conn)
                    .ExecuteNonQuery();
                new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] ([Name], [Par1]) VALUES ('Name 2', '2')", conn)
                    .ExecuteNonQuery();

                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader?.Read() == true)
                    Console.Out.WriteLine($"Name: {reader[0]}, Par1: {reader[1]}");
                reader?.Close();
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the 2007 and 2010 engines, both installed and was working properly, I did install both everywhere else. the problem now exists even on the V machine, which was working fine earlier.. I added the `mode=ReadWrite` attribute and it caused a problem so I removed it and the file became read only. I will still try installing later engines and test.

Comment: @bakz without being able to replicate the error it's very difficult to offer advice.

Comment: @bakz does the excel file contain macros?

Comment: no it does not contain any macros, it is a clean sheet I made which i also populated myself.. I don't know how can you replicate the problem, the V machine that did not have that problem now has it and I don't know why.. all I did is change the connection string and then reverted change. this is maddening

Comment: @bakz, ok, don't panic, try not to change the connection string randomly to try an make this work. Be methodical about it. What is the new connection string you are using. Then one that has caused V machine to no longer work. If I can replicate error here with same connection string then all the better. Also what is the name of the file?

Comment: I only added "ReadOnly=false" to the connection string, but since it is an extended attribute i placed it badly and did not work, to i returned the connection string back to it's original working version but the error started occurring in the V Machine... I can't even circle around what could cause this problem.

Comment: @bakz step away from your code for a moment and try the above code on it's own. Test the engine using some code that is known to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static DataSet GetDataSet(string fileName)
    {
        //string connectionString = $"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='{fileName}';Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;\"";
        string connectionString = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source='{fileName}';Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;\"";
        var data = new DataSet();
        foreach (var sheetName in GetExcelSheetNames(connectionString))
        {
            using (var con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }
                var query = $"SELECT * FROM [{sheetName}]";
                var dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
                var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con);
                adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                data.Tables.Add(dataTable);
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
    private static string[] GetExcelSheetNames(string connectionString)
    {
        using (var con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            var dt = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            if (dt == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            var excelSheetNames = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
            int i = 0;
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                excelSheetNames[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                i++;
            }
            con.Close();
            return excelSheetNames;
        }
    }
```

This is how I did it